# Changed App Name But Still Cannot Find It from google play search

Tags: android, android-studio, search, google-play, rename

Hello I published my android application to the google play about a month ago. I recently changed my app name from Calcy 7 Pro to Calcy Unit Converter. But when I use the search bar in the google play store 
if I search for Calcy Unit Converter I cannot find anything.
but if I search Calcy 7 Pro I find Calcy Unit Converter. I want that my app can be findable with the search of Calcy Unit Converter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play Store updates their search alghoritms about every two/three days. You can try to put your app name inside the description and add a lot of tags, it might help a little bit. Also remember that the main factor about searching apps is number of downloads.